# Google+ share count error

Tags: google-api, share, google-plus

I'm having a problem finding the share count of a website in google+.I've done the facebook, tweeter etc but i cant figure out how to do it in google+. I have searched this solution but only it returns 0.

```
function get_plusones($url) {
  $curl = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://clients6.google.com/rpc");
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, '[{"method":"pos.plusones.get","id":"p","params":{"nolog":true,"id":"' . $url . '","source":"widget","userId":"@viewer","groupId":"@self"},"jsonrpc":"2.0","key":"p","apiVersion":"v1"}]');
 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-type: application/json'));
 $curl_results = curl_exec ($curl);
 curl_close ($curl);
 $json = json_decode($curl_results, true);
 return intval( $json[0]['result']['metadata']['globalCounts']['count'] );
```

}

What have i done wrong?Any solution?

Comment: Now the google+ doesn't return the URL share counts :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution didn't put www in front of the url.

Comment: The solution is that you need to put the exact URL. Some websites have `www`, some not.